# How do I build an object array such that I get a properly formatted JSON output to match what is required?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I need to produce a json formatted array. My query returns an array for org ids and names.  I need the format of the output to be as seen below:

```
"orgs": [
    {
        "org_id":"1", 
        "org_name":"ABC"
    },
    {
        "org_id":"2", 
        "name":"DEF"
    },
    {
        "org_id":"3", 
        "name":"GHI"
    }
]
```

Instead I am getting the following:

```
{"0":{"org_id":1,"org_name":"ABC"},"1":{"org_id":2,"org_name":"DEF"}}
```

I am fairly new to OO coding within PHP, so I am not sure how to properly load my array to then be JSON encoded.  I have tried the following, but am not quite getting the right result:

```
$orgs = get_orgs();
$userorgs = array();
if ( is_array($orgs) && !empty($orgs) ) {
    foreach ($orgs as $key => $value) {
        if ( !empty($value['short_name']) ) {
            $userorgs[] = (object) ['org_id' => $value['org_id'], 'org_name' => $value['short_name']];
        } else {
            $userorgs[] = (object) ['org_id' => $value['org_id'], 'org_name' => $value['long_name']];
        }
    }
}

$json_orgs = json_encode($userorgs, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
echo $json_orgs;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of loading data is fine. You need to remove the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag from your call to [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). `json_encode` will automatically generate objects for associative arrays, but with that flag it will also turn numerically indexed arrays into objects.

For example (based on your data):

```
$arr = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'org_id' => 1,
    'org_name' => 'ABC',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'org_id' => 2,
    'org_name' => 'DEF',
  ),
);
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "\n";
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "org_id": 1,
        "org_name": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "org_id": 2,
        "org_name": "DEF"
    }
]
{
    "0": {
        "org_id": 1,
        "org_name": "ABC"
    },
    "1": {
        "org_id": 2,
        "org_name": "DEF"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, while I am not overly familiar with OO coding php, I wondered what was wrong.  Thank you so much!